# replacing text with a single backslash

Tags: r

I have this text and I want to replace `//` with `\`

This is the text  `sdfd//dfsadfs`

and I want it to be `sdfd\dfsadfs`

Can gsub work?  This does not work: `gsub("//","[\]","sdfd//dfsadfs")`

Comment: `"sdfd\dfsadfs"` is an invalid string in r. You can get `"sdfd\\dfsadfs"` with `sub("//","\\\\","sdfd//dfsadfs")`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem before. Like ***@Psidom*** commented, you should use `gsub("//","\\\\","sdfd//dfsadfs")`. This will replace `//`(2 characters) with `\\` which is actually a single character in R (Check by running `nchar("\\")`). Even though it is prints as `\\`, it behaves as `\`. You can check this by running `cat("\\")`. If you exported the data after running `gsub` to a table (or csv), I believe there will be only one `\`